# Create new column conditionally from other df columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I want to create a new boolean column in df1 if it meets both conditions in two columns of df2. For example:

```
df1:
   ID         Date
01234    8-23-2020
01234    8-26-2020
01235    8-24-2020
01235     9-3-2020
01236     9-1-2020

df2:
   id       visit
01234    8-23-2020
01235     9-3-2020
```

I want to make 'True' in df1 only the visits in df2, with a result like:

```
df1:
   ID         Date    In_store
01234    8-23-2020        1
01234    8-26-2020        0
01235    8-24-2020        0
01235     9-3-2020        1
01236     9-1-2020        0
```

I've tried:

```
pos_id = df2['id'].tolist()
pos_date = df2['visit'].tolist()

for row in df:
    if df1['ID'].isin(pos_id) and df1['Date'].isin(pos_visit):
        df1['In_store'] = 1
    else: 
        df1['In_store'] = 0
```

But I get:
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

And I've tried:

```
for row in df:
    if df1['ID'] == df2['ID'] and df1['Date'] == df2['Date']:
        df1['In_store'] = 1
    else: 
        df1['In_store'] = 0
```

But i get:
"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" even after renaming the colums the same.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially merge:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID','Date'], right_on=['id','visit'], how='left')

df1['In_store'] = merged['visit'].notna().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
     ID       Date  In_store
0  1234  8-23-2020         1
1  1234  8-26-2020         0
2  1235  8-24-2020         0
3  1235   9-3-2020         1
4  1236   9-1-2020         0
```

Comment: Thank, this worked. Unfortuantely, some id's in my final new column didnt match id's in df2. I'm gonna do some more digging into what I might have missed